# Find a list of stopped services using user input wildcard

Tags: powershell, wildcard

i'm trying to create a power shell script that when executed, will list all stopped services matching a specific, user input wildcard.  I would like for the wildcard to be saved as a string, then used in get service.  Here's what I have so far.

```
 param([string] $SearchPrefix=$(throw "Please specify the search prefix:"))


 Get-Service  | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $SearchPrefix} | foreach {$_.Status} | foreach {$_.Name}
```

I'm new to learning Powershell so i'm a bit stuck.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-eq` with `-match`

- `-eq` is for strict equality
- `-match`is for patterns. If you asked for a prefix then add a Circumflex Accent at start: `$_.Name -match "^$SearchPrefix"`

As a side note, your two last foreach are useless and will block ouput AFAICS.

```
Get-Service  | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $SearchPrefix}
```

will output something like

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  WinHttpAutoProx... Service de découverte automatique d...
Stopped  WinRM              Gestion à distance de Windows (Gest...
```

If you want only the two first columns, then add

```
| Format-Table -auto -property Status, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want a list of stopped services which starts with wc.

```
PS C:\> $SearchPrefix = "wc*"
PS C:\> Get-Service -Name $SearchPrefix | where{$_.status -eq 'Stopped'}

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  wcncsvc            Windows Connect Now - Config Registrar
Stopped  WcsPlugInService   Windows Color System
```